# Delphi Use keys to navigate in a viewlist

Tags: delphi

Hello again programmers I excuse the last question. Bad info gives bad answer :) I will try to explain with a better example. I am using a TListview in Delphi XE3 (I know it's not good for this use) and below I have the code on key down.

But first I fill the listview with data:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Var
I,C : Integer;
  Item : TListItem;
begin
for C := 0 to 8 do
begin
   ListView1.Columns[C].caption := 'Ip Address '+ IntToStr(C);

    Item:=ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Caption:=Format('%d.%d',[i,1]);
  Item.SubItems.Add(Format('%d.%d',[i,2]));
  Item.SubItems.Add(Format('%d.%d',[i,3]));
  Item.SubItems.Add(Format('%d.%d',[i,4]));
  Item.SubItems.Add(Format('%d.%d',[i,5]));
  Item.SubItems.Add(Format('%d.%d',[i,6]));
  Item.SubItems.Add(Format('%d.%d',[i,7]));
  Item.SubItems.Add(Format('%d.%d',[i,8]));

end;
end;
```

//Then on keydown

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
Shift: TShiftState);
Var LItem: TListItem;
begin
if Key = VK_RETURN  then
if Assigned(ListView1.Selected) then
ListView1.Selected.EditCaption;
```

So far so good. Now after ending editing the cell I need to use Left and Right Arrow to navigate to the left or right of selected cell, among the  subitems. And I need the Listview to shadow or draw a frame around the cell when I navigate (Like excel). The Listview should be in Report view mode, but still show the frame around selected cell. Also I need to set that, for Example only col 3, 5 and 6 should be possible to go to with keys.

I tried whit some code, but It doesn't work.
Below is how I started.

```
if Key in [VK_LEFT,VK_RIGHT] then

case Key  of
VK_LEFT:   if ListView1.Selected.Index < ListView1.Columns.Count +1 then
             begin

               end;

VK_RIGHT:  if ListView1.Selected.Index > ListView1.Selected.Index -1 then  

 Begin 

        end;
end;
```

Any help would be great...
Thank you in advance.
PS I have tested other enhanced Listviews and there it's not a problem. But the system I built with standard Listview is so complexed so I want to use the standard for now...

Best Regards...

Comment: I don't know it exactly but i think you can only select a line with a TListView, no SubItem Columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `TStringGrid` component. With it, it's possible to switch columns with the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the `TListView` control which is a wrapper around the Windows list view control, SysListView32. Well, I expect that if you paint the control yourself then it would become possible, but I'm going to assume that you don't want to do that.

You have two main properties that influence selection. The first is controlled by the `RowSelect` property. If that is `False` then you can highlight and select only the first column. If `RowSelect` is `True` then you can highlight and select an entire row. The second switch is the `MultiSelect` property which controls whether or not multiple rows can be selected.

I suspect that you will need to switch to a different control to achieve your goals. I expect that Mike Lischke's Virtual Tree View control can be persuaded to behave in the way you desire.